# Delete string between tags using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Given an input string like this:

```
"blah <b>abc <i>foo</i> GETME bar </b> GETME <b>something else</b>"
```

I'd like to write a PERL regex that produces a result string like:

```
"blah <b>abc <i>foo</i>  bar </b> GETME <b>something else</b>
```

where the "GETME" between the `<b>` and `</b>` has been removed.  Basically I want to remove all instances of "GETME" in between the starting `<b>` and ending `</b>` tags.

I've seen there's a "Balanced" package that deals with this but it seems to be overkill.  Are there simpler solutions?

Something like:

```
$teststr =~ s/(<b>[^>]*?)GETME(.*?<\/b>)/$1$2/g;
```

works but only if there's not a nested tag like a `<i>` in between the `<b>` and `</b>`.

Ideally I could write something like:

```
$teststr =~ s/<b>(.*?)</b>/{$1 =~ s/GETME//g}/g;
```

where I nest another regex but if something like that is possible, I don't know the syntax.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la  My preferred parser is `HTML::TokeParser`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a parser, for example, `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => {
        'b' => sub {
            $_->subs_text( qr{\bGETME\b}, '' );
            $_->print;
        },  
    },  
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
)->parse(
    '<root>blah <b>abc <i>foo</i> GETME bar </b> GETME <b>something</b></root>'
);
```

It yields:

```
<root>blah <b>abc <i>foo</i>  bar </b> GETME <b>something</b></root>
```